# pass data between different viewport

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

in my program there is a 'Screen' with two TextField and one Button..

the button have this listener;

```
listeners: {
    tap: function (as, e, eOpts ) {
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem({xtype: 'clientlist'},{ type:'flip'})},
    },
}
```

so pressing the button I go to another screen…

in the second screen I want to use a Label where I want to see the words that I write in the first screen.. so how I can port the text (in the textfiels of first screen) in the new screen?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the MVC format:

View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.FirstScreen', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'textField1',
                label: 'Field'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'textField2',
                label: 'Field'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'mybutton1',
                text: 'click me'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'First Screen'
            }
        ]
    }

});    

// Client List (Second Screen)
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ClientList', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.clientlist',

    config: {
        itemId: 'clientList',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Client List'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController1', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            textField1: '#textField1',
            textField2: '#textField2',
            clientList: {
                autoCreate: true,
                selector: '#clientList',
                xtype: 'clientlist'
            }
        },

        control: {
            "button#mybutton1": {
                tap: 'onMybutton1Tap'
            }
        }
    },

    onMybutton1Tap: function(button, e, options) {
        var me  = this,
            clientList = me.getClientList(),
            textField1_val = me.getTextField1().getValue(),
            textField2_val = me.getTextField2().getValue();

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(clientList,{ type:'flip'});

        // Do what you need to do with the values from your 
        // first screen in your client list
        clientList.setHtml('textField1_data: '+textField1_val+'<br>textField2_data: '+ textField2_val);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks!
do you now why if i do "var usernameLabel = this.getUsernameLabel();" and after "usernameLabel.setHtml("we");", i get "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'usernameLabel.setHtml')"
? (the code is the same)

Comment: If you are accessing your label via your controller, ensure that it as an `itemId` and that you reference it in your controller similar to how your textfields are referenced. So assuming you give your label an itemId of `usernameLabel`, you should be able to do `this.getUsernameLabel()`.